# Can you target _blank with useNavigate?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

In my react redux project, I need to navigate to a new page to maintain my redux store, but  I want to do so in a new tab, rather than changing the route of the current tab. Is there a way to do something like useNavigate("/route", target=_blank) or is that not possible?

Comment: Once you're in a new window/tab, you have to reload all of the JS anyway, so using RRD to do the navigation actually doesn't benefit you any. The big advantage of client side routing is that no page refresh is required, in a new tab it's unavoidable.

Comment: That said, they may have it in the API just for convenience.. I don't know for sure.

Comment: Not with [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate). `navigate` function takes either of (1) a [`to`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#to) target and `options` object with `replace` and `state` properties, or (2) a `delta` number to go forward/backward. You may be able to use [useHref](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usehref) hook.

Comment: Hey @DrewReese it's you again! Would there be any way to open in a new tab without actually needing react router? I'm trying to figure out react-state-sync at the moment in the hopes that it would remove the need to use navigate at all but if I don't even need to go to a different route that would solve the problem.

Comment: Is this just a page in your app, or an external URL, that you want to open in a new tab/window? Either way, I guess you will want to check out [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: @DrewReese this is just a page in my app. Originally this was an SPA where the page would change to this current one, but it was specifically requested that this one specific page open up in a new tab instead, something that I'm having trouble getting to work with redux as the state does not transfer over to the new tab that has opened.

Comment: Right... I think for that you'll need to also have implemented a redux state persistence so you can open the app in any window and it loads/initializes the store from localStorage.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah that's what I was assuming. Thank you for the help. Hopefully that will work

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that redux-persist did the job so there was no need for useNavigation. I just did a regular link with target blank and made sure the information held through tabs.